# The area of trapezium is given by $A=(a^2-x^2)(x+a)$. Find x for the area to be a maximum and find A max.

Tags: calculus, area

For the diagram, the area of trapezium is given by $A=(a^2-x^2)(x+a)$. Find $x$ for the area to be a maximum and find $A$ max.

Hi, I'm not sure how should i do this question. Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/unL3n.jpg

Comment: Differentiate as usual.We get  $a^2-2ax-3x^2$. Set equal to $0$ and solve. Luckily the quadratic factors as $-(3x-a)(x+a)$. Argue that $x=a/3$ really gives the max.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas. But it doesn't seems a/3 to be an area as it is not a number. If you can be more specific that will help me more.

Comment: You are welcome. For the maximum area plug into the formula for $A$. And $a$ is a number, albeit an unspecified one. The parabola has equation $y=a^2-x^2$, so it is not completely numerically specified.

Comment: ohh....thanks for the help.